# Dynamic binding jquery plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

In jQuery you can dynamically bind an event listener to all future instances of divs with a class of 'subthing' by binding to a parent element and assigning a filter like so:

```
$(".thing").on("click", ".subthing", function(){ 
  console.log('subthing clicked');}
);
```

If I have a jquery plugin that I would ordinarily bind with

```
$(".subthing").thingify();
```

Is there an established way ensure that all future instances of .subthing will also have the plugin attached to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
document.body.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event){
    var $elementJustAdded = $(event.target);
    if ($elementJustAdded.hasClass('subthing')) {
        $elementJustAdded.thingify();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: That's a good point, and it accomplishes my primary objective of getting the JS out of the partial that adds the element. I'm going to look in to how to do this with mutation observers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [livequery plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery)

```
$(".subthing").livequery(function(){        
    $(this).thingify(); 
});
```

I think this is exactly what you need.

Comment: link is broken please repair link address